# Configuring iptables by software

Tags: linux, iptables

Is there a software, or a linux distro which has such a software built-in, which makes configuring the iptables easier? If not,
I thought that some of the mostly used configuarations with a simple GUI can make it easier but I couldn't find any. Do you think it's a need? 
If there is, how can I find it?

Comment: Ubuntu comes with [ufw](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncomplicated_Firewall)

Comment: I am really unexperienced about linux distros, I didn't know that. Thanks a lot.

Comment: have you tried webmin ? http://www.trbailey.net/tech/iptables.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some options:

- [Uncomplicated Firewall](https://launchpad.net/ufw)(ufw). This is the option that comes with ubuntu, and its focus is made firewall rules easy
- [Shorewall](http://www.shorewall.net/). Focused on servers and network routers/gateways/firewall, working with zones.
- [Vuurmuur](http://www.vuurmuur.org/trac/). Focused on easy to use, build with a ncurses interface, similar with the `iptraf` tool.
- [Firewall Builder](http://www.fwbuilder.org/). GUI firewall, with a focus of "easy to use" too.
- [Webmin](http://www.webmin.com/). A more "generic" kind of control panel to Linux, that have a firewall rules manager.

**Other references**:

- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Firewalls
- https://wiki.debian.org/Firewalls